# \vspace after \vfill ignored

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

```
\vfill
Text first line
\vspace{1cm}
Text second line
\cleardoublepage
```

The `\vspace` is unfortunately ignored by LaTeX: The resulting document has no vertical space added between the two lines. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a) *something* (e.g., an empty box) before `\vfill` (assuming `\vfill` is at the top of the page) b) a paragraph between the first and second line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Text first line

\vspace{1cm}
Text second line
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is what to do, the "why" is that the vspace is not ignored but if you use vspace mid-paragraph it does not force a linebreak, the paragraph breaks as usual and the extra vertical space is added after the current line, in the MWE that would be at the end of the document.